# most elegant way to hardcode pair, triplet ... values

Tags: c++

I have an enum.

And for each value in this enum, I need to associate with it some data (actually in this case, it's an integer, but I would like to know more generally, for instance 2 integer values, or 2 strings etc).

Those values can't be accessible by the user. In the case of reverse engineering, well, can't do much, but it should ask the user some effort to actually modify it. So it can't be in a config file or in a DB etc.

So I was thinking about:

1. Hardcode them but in this case, what's the most elegant (least horrible) method? Just hardcode a Pair, triplet in a namespace that I then store in a hash [enumValue]->[struct]?
2. store it in a file that will be compiled as resource file (although this is accessible with some tools, it will ask a bit more effort from the user). I could even do a checksum to make sure it wasn't modified if necessary I guess?

What are your thoughts?

To summarize, I have an enum containing VAL1, VAL2 ...

and I would like to associate like:

VAL1 has for length 5 and name "foo"
VAL2 has for length 8 and name "bar"

I might be completely missing an other easy solution though

Comment: [http://www.kolpackov.net/projects/c++/enum/class.xhtml](http://www.kolpackov.net/projects/c++/enum/class.xhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code was adapted from a solution I found a while ago on another stackoverflow post - if anyone can find the original link again I'll include it to give credit to them.

I had a similar problem where I wanted to associate a `string` with each enum value. Adapting that code slightly for your case of a pair of values I get this.

```
template<typename T> class EnumParser
{
    private:
        std::map<T, std::pair<int, std::string>> _map_enum_keyed;   // Map with enum values as keys

    public:
        EnumParser();   // Unspecified constructor
        T Enum(const std::string &key) const;   // Get the enum value for the given string key
        std::pair<int, std::string> Value(const T &key) const;  // Get the string value of the given enum key
};

// Template definitions

template<typename T>
std::pair<int, std::string> EnumParser<T>::Value(const T &key) const
{
    const auto &iterator = this->_map_enum_keyed.find(key);
    if(iterator == this->_map_enum_keyed.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("EnumParser::Value(const T &key) - error 1 - Could not find key");
    }
    return iterator->second;
}
```

You then can use this in the **cpp** file associated with the **header** where your `enum` was declared by specifying the constructor for an EnumParser initialised with that `enum`

```
template<>EnumParser<YOUR_ENUM>::EnumParser()
{
    this->_map_enum_keyed = {
        {YOUR_ENUM::Value1, std::make_pair(5, "foo")},
        {YOUR_ENUM::Value2, std::make_pair(8, "bar")},
    };
}
```

You can make this more general by adding a second template parameter and replacing where I used `std::pair` with that second template.

This was particularly useful when wanting to associate an `enum` with a `std::string` as you can add in a second map with `std::string` as the keys and the template parameter as the values. By simply reversing the original map you can then turn a `string` into an `enum` as well as being able to turn an `enum` into a `string`